# How can I embed Google Trends into a Jupyter Notebook? (on kaggle)

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, google-trends

I am trying to embed a Google Trends chart into my Notebook on Kaggle, It basically helps the user validate & verify Insights / findings.

I've tried the following method, I am not able to see any outputs, I tried this on kaggle notebooks as well,

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

Javascript("""
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/3140_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"/m/0fp_8fm","geo":"IN","time":"today 12-m"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"q=%2Fm%2F0fp_8fm&geo=IN&date=today 12-m","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"}); </script>
           """)
```

and

```
display(HTML("""
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js"></script>
"""))
```

I am expecting an embed of the Google Trends chart below my cell,
I would really appreciate any sort of help and advice on this, Thanks a lott